# Trigger produces no output

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Why does the trigger have no output and is not created?

```
create trigger chronik BEFORE UPDATE 
ON eastatus_t
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    insert into sendechronik_t(mandant, fk_eakopf_posnr, lfd_nr, statusdatum, fk_statusart_mc, statuszeit, fk_ort_status)
    SELECT (mandant, fk_eakopf_posnr, lfd_nur, statusdatum, fk_statusart_mc, statuszeit, fk_ort_status)
    FROM eastatus_t
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Trigger cannot output something by default. And must not.

Comment: *Why does the trigger ... is not created?* Syntax error. No query terminator.

Comment: When i execute it, there will nothing be shown in the output, and nothin after show errors;

Comment: Meanwile i have an error: 18:07:22 insert into sendechronik_t(mandant, fk_eakopf_posnr, lfd_nr, statusdatum, fk_statusart_mc, statuszeit, fk_ort_status)  SELECT (mandant, fk_eakopf_posnr, lfd_nur, statusdatum, fk_statusart_mc, statuszeit, fk_ort_status)     FROM eastatus_t Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'lfd_nr' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: *Unknown column 'lfd_nr' in 'field list'* What is unclear in this words?

Comment: lfd_nr exist in a table but why not in field list?

Comment: Provide: CREATE TABLE for both tables; the goal which you want to achieve by the trigger.

Comment: Now i have the error message not any more, when intest the insert, the only problem is there, that he have more then one row. Now i have tried to create the trigger again and nothing happened